# Certain part of object showing up black in Cycles rendered view

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm currently working on a bedroom project in Blender while following a tutorial. I thought I was completing all the steps correctly. But when I entered rendered view, specific parts of my wall showed up as black. I have lighting and I do not have any textures added to my scene. None of the other objects are doing this. How do I fix this?

[image: Black wall, even though there are no textures added to it]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com. Most likely you have duplicate vertices or objects overlapping each other.

Comment: I think this is it: https://blend-exchange.com/b/OsmXJW7G - Let me know if that works!

Comment: You wrote you have no textures added, but textures ≠ materials. Are there no materials on the objects? Because if you start modeling with the default cube for example, this usually has a basic material - a _Principled BSDF_ with 80% white color plugged into a _Material Output_. Let's say you have this basic material on the object, delete the _Principled BSDF_ but leave the _Material Output_ - this would look exactly like that. But everything else is just guesswork without any screenshots of materials or the file.

Comment: Here is the blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/OsmXJW7G

I don't believe I have any materials or textures added to the cube. It also only appears as black in Cycles, not Eevee.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, no need for double-posting (writing my comment overlapped with you posting it) - by the way, on the download site it says "Share this file: Add this text into your post:" and you can edit the whole text into your question.

Comment: i have just confirmed it is really the duplicate vertices. just select the object and go into edit mode then press `a` then `m` then *Merge By Distance*. solved :)

Comment: Omg thank you so much!! You're a life saver, I hope you have an awesome day. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie That's right, you're quicker than me. Post this as an answer so one can see it is solved, because many people have problems with duplicate vertices.

Comment: Okay, thank you! :D I just signed up to this site so I wasn't sure about that. It's solved now- I just had to merge the vertices by distance. Once again, thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: alright! hey no problem! glad we were able to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Seeing black textures in Cycles rendering is commonly caused by either overlapping objects of the same geometry or duplicate overlapping vertices. These scenarios cause the render engine to mess up the calculation of lighting. In your case it is duplicate vertices. To solve this just select the object and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices then press <kbd>M</kbd> and choose *Merge By Distance*.